# Two different results of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I was calculating an integral $$\int_{-i}^{i} \frac{1}{z} \,dz$$, but why here I get two different results?[image]

Comment: The function $1/z$ Is holomorphic (and defined) only on the punctured plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, which is not simply connected, hence the integrals like $\int_{a}^{b} 1/z dz$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ depends on the chosen path between $a,b$. So strictly speaking the integral $\int_{a}^b 1/z dz$ doesnt even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting two different results because you're calculating two different integrals!

The first method seems to consider: $$\int_{-i}^i:=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\left(\int_{-i}^{-\delta i}+\int_{\delta i}^i+\oint_{\gamma_\delta}\right)$$As a regularised integral whereas the second method seems to consider: $$\int_{-i}^i:=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\left(\int_{-i}^{-\delta i}+\int_{\delta i}^i\right)$$The definitions are different, so it is no wonder that the answers are different.